# MongoDB update sub array

Tags: mongodb-query

I'm really new to MongoDB and am experiencing an issue with an update operation.  This is the document:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15c00"),
"name" : "Phone Service Family Plan",
"type" : "service",
"monthly_price" : 90,
"limits" : {
        "voice" : {
                "units" : "minutes",
                "n" : 1200,
                "over_rate" : 0.05
        },
        "data" : {
                "n" : "unlimited",
                "over_rate" : 0
        },
        "sms" : {
                "n" : "unlimited",
                "over_rate" : 0
        }
},
"sales_tax" : true,
"term_years" : 3
```

I want to update over_rate for sms in limits to 0.01 from 0.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this? (first argument in update being the document you want to update)

```
 db.objects.update({name:"something"},{"$set":{"limits.sms":{"over_rate":0.01}}})
```